# Link error with Boost on Android

Tags: android, boost, android-ndk

I've successfully built some of the boost-libraries but when I include them in a test project I get link errors.

```
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
Compile++ thumb  : hello-jni <= test.cpp
SharedLibrary  : libhello-jni.so
libboost_timer.a(cpu_timer.o): In function `~basic_iostream':
/opt/android-ndk-r7/sources/boost/../../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/istream:795: undefined reference to `VTT for std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
libboost_timer.a(cpu_timer.o): In function `show_time':
/opt/android-ndk-r7/sources/boost/libs/timer/src/cpu_timer.cpp:61: undefined reference to `VTT for std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
/opt/android-ndk-r7/sources/boost/libs/timer/src/cpu_timer.cpp:61: undefined reference to `vtable for std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
/opt/android-ndk-r7/sources/boost/libs/timer/src/cpu_timer.cpp:61: undefined reference to `vtable for std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
libboost_timer.a(cpu_timer.o): In function `boost::timer::format(boost::timer::cpu_times const&, short, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/opt/android-ndk-r7/sources/boost/libs/timer/src/cpu_timer.cpp:177: undefined reference to `std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS = -fexceptions
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c test.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := boost_timer, boost_system
LOCAL_LDLIBS := libboost_system.a libboost_timer.a libboost_chrono.a libboost_iostreams.a
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
  $(call import-module,boost)
```

And test.cpp

```
#include "test.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>

void mytest() {
boost::timer::cpu_timer t;
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: Nah, still waiting for a kind soul with über-likning-skills to come to the rescue.

Answer (score 1):

we had very similar problem. What helped for us is to add `-lgnustl_static` at the end of the  LOCAL_LDLIBS line in Android.mk. Like this:

```
LOCAL_LDIBS := -lboost_system .... -lgnustl_static
```

I think this is because boost libraries depend on STL but don't have it statically compiled in, so it needs to be mentioned explicitly like that.

Also, it seems you don't have to add the `APP_STL := gnustl_static` line to the `Application.mk`.